# Possible to use tf.distribute.Strategy.mirroredstrategy on parts of the graph rather than entire train_step for GAN custom training script?

Tags: python, tensorflow, distributed-computing, generative-adversarial-network, multiple-gpu

I'm writing CTGAN code and want it to train in a distributed way.
Therefore I'm using [tf.distribute.Strategy.mirroredstrategy()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distribute/MirroredStrategy)
In the [tensorflow docs tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/custom_training) I'm following, it is mentioned that you should call your train_step code from a function called distribute_trainstep(), and decorate that with a tf.function. like so:

```
@tf.function
def distributed_train_step(dataset_inputs):
  per_replica_losses = strategy.run(train_step, args=(dataset_inputs,))
  return strategy.reduce(tf.distribute.ReduceOp.SUM, per_replica_losses,
                         axis=None)
```

This is straightforward, but decorating all within train_step in a tf.function renders all numpy code within the train_step useless. What should I do? Is there an alternative, by only wrapping functions within train_step selectively? Or will I have to replace all numpy operations with tensorflow's?

Comment: Why are you using numpy code in your train step?

Comment: Mostly because it was already written like this. Don't know why this was done in the first place, but it will take a while to rewrite